# Select all values (all rows) in one row Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, window-functions

I get multiple rows after executing the **select**-query.
But I need to get all the values of these rows in one row.

̶C̶o̶u̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶u̶n̶k̶n̶o̶w̶n̶ ̶(̶b̶e̶f̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶*̶*̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶*̶*̶-̶q̶u̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶c̶u̶t̶e̶d̶)̶

For example:

```
|----------|-----------|
| **Name** | **Value** |
|----------|-----------|
|   Alex   |    150    |
|----------|-----------|
|   Peter  |    220    |
|----------|-----------|
|   Katty  |     34    |
|----------|-----------|
```

I want to get:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| **Col_1** | **Col_2** | **Col_3** | **Col_4** | **Col_5** | **Col_6** |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|    Alex   |    150    |    Peter  |    220    |    Katty  |     34    |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Oracle 11g.

***UPDATE***: I realized that with an unknown number of rows, the task is difficult, so I can assume that the number of rows will be known.

Comment: You say you don't know how many rows there are before hand. Oracle projections have a hard limit of 1000 columns. So you cannot generate a result for more than input 500 rows. Is that likely in your scenario?

Comment: @APC The result of my query will definitely fit into the specified limit on the number of columns. I thought it would be easy to write such a request. But I couldn't do it. Isn't that so?

Comment: Can't pivot be used here?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way for dynamic pivot for Oracle's SQL, but [this link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HPN95108FSSZD87PXX7MG3LW3.html) might provide a perception for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

To pivot over a fixed number of column, one option uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when rn = 1 then name end) name1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then value end) value1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then name end) name2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then value end) value2,
    ...
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
```

You need a column that defines the ordering of the rows in the original dataset (and of the columns in the resultset): I assumed `id`.

Comment: The Seeker clearly states in the question that the count of rows is unknown, hence the number of columns in the final projection is unknowable.

Comment: @APC And if we assume that the number of rows would have been known to me in advance? Then is this method good?

Comment: @ColaClassic - if you know the number of rows in advance then you can hardcode the column names like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off putting the values into a string or JSON column.  For instance, you can aggregate the names and values into separate strings:

```
select list_agg(name, ',') within group (order by name) as names,
       list_agg(value, ',') within group (order by name) as values
from t;
```

Or into a single string:

```
select list_agg(name || ':' || value, ',') within group (order by name) as name_values
from t;
```

Note:  The maximum length of strings in Oracle for this purpose is 2000 characters.  So this only works on a small amount of data.

Comment: thanks for the answer! but I need all data to be stored in separate cells